# An update for template pack is available

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, command-line

Every time I run this command now:

```
dotnet new console -o a
```

I get this:

```
An update for template pack Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.5.0::5.0.0
   is available.
install command: dotnet new -i Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.5.0::5.0.1
```

I don't want DotNet checking for updates, ever, and certainly not "patch" level updates. How do I disable this? I tried `$env:DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT = 1`, but it doesn't seem to change the update behavior.

Comment: Did you try with `--no-restore` option?

Comment: @Fabio that doesnt change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, this isn't .NET checking for updates to .NET itself, it's checking for updates to the templates. Having stale templates could have a security implication if a template generates code that's vulnerable.

But your concern stands: it's making network connections to machines not under your control and sending data that you might consider private.

I am looking at the source code that implements this check and there doesn't appear to be a way to configure this at this time.

The error message is printed by [`TemplateInvocationAndAcquisitionCoordination.DisplayUpdateMessage`](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/4b3f8ea9a01fc7f0da6c7dde6e2de87cfaa3eeaf/src/Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli/TemplateInvocationAndAcquisitionCoordinator.cs#L104). Neither that file, nor the actual checker in [`TemplateUpdateChecker`](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/master/src/Microsoft.TemplateSearch.Common/TemplateUpdate/TemplateUpdateChecker.cs) seem to have a way to configure this check.

I think you should file a bug against [dotnet/templating](https://github.com/dotnet/templating) repo requesting this.